# exe created from py2exe returns: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CUIAutomation'"

Tags: python, py2exe, pywin32, pywinauto

Its a simple GUI Script written with tinkter module of python. and Putty tool is called to make some SSH connections. Issue seems to be with compatibilty.
python version : 3.4
pywinauto version : 0.6.2
py2exe version : 0.9.2.2

the created exe file are opening in some windows 7 PCs and throw some error in others. All PCs are Windows 7.

traceback from the cmd;

```
C:\tools\easy_Login\easy_Login>easy_login.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):



File "easy_login.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 40, in <modul
e>


File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 42, in <mo
dule>



File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 36,
in <module>



File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 44
, in <module>



 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 175, in <module>

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 163, in _build_pattern_ids_dic
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 50, in __call__
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 63, in __init__

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CUIAutomation'
C:\tools\easy_Login\easy_Login>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming your your source python script *"login.py"* rather than *"easy_login.py"* then re-run py2exe to create *"login.exe"*

It sounds odd, but I had the exact same issue with some W7 machines throwing that error when I was running *"ateme_installer.exe"* (generated with pyinstaller) and after ruling out all other issues, eventually found that when I renamed it *"installer.py"* and suddenly the output *"installer.exe"* worked everywhere!